# Changing circle's gradient color?

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I'm trying to change the color of a circles gradient after it has been instantiated. I've tried applying a ColorFilter but that doesn't seem to support gradients. How would I accomplish this?

I draw the flare like this

```
    flare.graphics
        .beginRadialGradientFill(["#f15a29","#000"], [0, 1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 250)
        .drawCircle(0, 0, 250);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to redraw it each tick if you want it to change. This sounds like it's not a performant option, however the Graphics class does this each tick anyways, so having clearing and redrawing a shape on tick is not much different.

You can also look into the `inject` method, which lets you define some methods that can affect the context when the Graphics redraws each time:

From the docs:

```
function setColor(color) {
    this.fillStyle = color;
}
// this will draw the rect in green:
myGraphics.beginFill("#000").inject(setColor, "green").drawRect(0,0,100,100);
```

http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Graphics.html#method_inject